# FFmpeg e BAT Conversão automático

Tags: cmd, vídeo, bat

Estou usando o ffmpeg para fazer conversão de todos os vídeos de uma pasta para .mp4, e para isso, criei um .bat para fazer o processo, mas, o problema que é seguinte:

Quando ele inicia a conversão, ele cria com mesmo mone um arquivo no formato e extensão .mp4.

Ocorre, que, se por acaso o processo é interrompido, ele removesse o arquivo .mp4 ainda não finalizado pela conversão.

Meu .bat roda pelo agendador de tarefa, assim, para a próxima execução, como o .bat foi interrompido, o meu .bat interrompe a execução  solicitando minha interação na para confinar a substituição do arquivo.mp4 não finalizado previamente

Gostaria que ele só criasse o outro arquivo.MP4 quando o processo de conversão finaliza-se sem interrupções, alguém pode me ajudar com esse script?

Segue o código ultilizado:

---

```all-bat
for /r %%F in (*.avi *.rmvb *.flv *.mov *.avi *.ts) do (
    ffmpeg.exe  -i "%%F"  -preset ultrafast "%%~dpnF.mp4"
    if not errorlevel 1 if exist   "%%~dpnF.mp4" del /q "%%F"
)
```

Comment: Para uma saída mais "verbose", remover o **`-v error -stats -vn`** .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - **Update** Opera **recursivamente** na conversão

---

Você pode usar um **`for`** num looping com o complemento **`-y`** junto oom o operador **`&&`**, que vai funcionar assim:

---

```bat
executa_sem_erro && então_execute_esse_porque_anterior_não_retornou_erro
executa_com_erro || então_execute_esse_porque_anterior_retornou_erro
```

---

Observe que o complemento **`-y`** vai informar o **`ffmpeg`** para executar as ações sobrescrevendo arquivo de destino/saída se existentes, assim, não sendo necessárias as futuras confirmações na execução agendada.

---

---

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" & color 0a 

rem :: edite comandos baixo adicionando caminho completo para pasta pertinentes e remova os "rem ::"
rem :: cd /d "drive:\pasta\sub_pasta\onde_tem_os_arquivos\videos"
rem :: set _ffmpeg=drive:\pasta\sub_pasta\onde_tem\bin\do\ffmpeg.exe"
rem :: como o ffmpeg esta na mesma pasta dos videos, set \_ffmpeg fica assim :: 

cd /d "drive:\pasta\sub_pasta\onde_tem_os_arquivos\videos" && set "_ffmpeg=.\ffmpeg.exe"

for %%F in (avi rmvb flv mov avi ts) do for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%c in ('dir /s /b "*.%%~F"')do (
     echo/ Origem_: "%%~c"
     echo/ Destino: "%%~dpnc.avi"
     !_ffmpeg! -y -i "%%~c" -preset ultrafast -v error -stats "%%~dpnc.mp4" && del "%%c" /q /f
     )
```

---

> - Para ficar em looping e se ja tens janela/bat rodando, vai verificar a cada segundo até não encontar, daí inicia as conversões porque a anterior ja´findou-se

- código sem os comentários e em looping aguardando execução anterior finalizar...

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" & color 9f

title <nul & goto :^[ 

:^]
title Script Convert Running...

cd /d "drive:\pats_user\User\outra\pasta\video"

for %%F in (avi rmvb flv mov avi ts)do for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%c in ('dir /s /b "*.%%~F"')do (
     echo/ Origem_: "%%~c" && echo/ Destino: "%%~dpnc.mp4" 
     ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%~c" -preset ultrafast -v error -stats "%%~dpnc.mp4" && del "%%c" /q /f
     echo/______________________________________________________________________________
     )

goto :^? 

:^[
%windir%\system32\tasklist /v |%windir%\system32\findstr.exe /lic:"Script Convert Running" >nul || goto :^] || %windir%\system32\tasklist\timeout /t 1 /nobreak & goto :^[

:^?
title <nul && exit /b
```